# Elasticbeanstalk controlling access

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, security, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have recently started development using Amazon web services. I built a sample application using the examples which worked well. I had assumed (wrongly) that was the only user that could navigate to the URL's since, I was logged in with my amazon credentials.

Apparently anyone can access the site without logging in to amazon - not something I want.

I have started looking at [AWS Userguide Security](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/EC2_Network_and_Security.html)

which is a start, I am looking for articles/web sites which will guide me through implementation of a secure web site hosted on amazon.

Comment: Check out VPC (Virtual Private Cloud). It is rather simple use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amazon credentials have nothing to do with the Web Application you have crafted.
Here are 2 options for you:

1. Introduce *Authentication* concept to your application: anything from simple http basic authentication (using standard Apachee / IIS modules. see [Apachee docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/auth.html)) to full blown users management, secured password storage, cookies, password change/reset flows etc...
2. Alternatively, you can use [Dome9](http://www.dome9.com/overview/features-tour) to block your web application at the network level and then grant yourself (or other users) 'Access Leases' using Dome9 portal.

Disclaimer: I'm a Dome9'er